# Converting from list of very small floats to a PyTorch tensor gives a TypeError because PyTorch interprets scientific notation as str instead of float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, tensor

I have data that I want to setup as a PyTorch tensor as my objective for a ML algorithm. If I inspect the list as is I get :

`ydata = [1.39e-11, 1.5e-12, 4.7e-16]`

I want to have this list in a tensor, so I tried multiple functions but everytime I get a TypeError for instance :

`torch.FloatTensor(ydata) -> TypeError('must be real number, not str')`

However if I inspect the type of each element of ydata it is a float. How can I go about getting the data I want into a tensor?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to replicate your example on my machine:

```
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

then:

```
import torch
ydata = ['1.39e-11', '1.5e-12', '4.7e-16']
ydata = [float(x) for x in ydata]   # convert your string to float
torch.FloatTensor(ydata)

#output
tensor([1.3900e-11, 1.5000e-12, 4.7000e-16])
```

Comment: Your comment made me realise my issue wasn't with my usage of PyTorch, but with my data, which had some values only be '-', which was indeed a str instead of float, I did some cleanup and my original code worked, thanks!

Comment: Awesome...you're welcome!